# How do I make a downloaded font as background?

Tags: html, css, fonts, background

I'm not allowed to use images so I am trying to make a font i downloaded as a background - and if it's possible on top of a regular color. I would like that the font (which is like an image) will repeat itself

How can I do that? 
I was trying different codes I saw over the internet but didn't understand them fully so I guess that is why they didn't work...

I did it in a paragraph but I would like to put it in the body as a background

html code

```
<p id="cookie1"> qqq </p> //shows a donut
<p id="cookie2"> qqq </p>
```

css code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: allCandy;
    src: url(SUGAC___.TTF);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: candy;
    src: url(PeppermintCanes.otf);
}


#cookie1 {
   font-family: allCandy;
   font-size: 30px;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#cookie2 {
   font-family: allCandy;
   font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example2;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    z-index: 10;
}




/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {color:#FFAABD; top:0%}
    25%  {color:#FF3D87; }
    50%  {color: #CB30FF; }
    100% {color: #FFAABD; top:95%}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {color:#FFAABD; top:0%}
    25%  {color:#FF3D87; }
    50%  {color: #CB30FF; }
    100% {color: #FFAABD; top:95%}
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example2 {
    0%   {color:#FFAABD; top:0%; left:80%}
    25%  {color:#FF3D87; }
    50%  {color: #CB30FF; }
    100% {color: #FFAABD; top:95%;  left:80%}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example2 {
    0%   {color:#FFAABD; top:0%; left:80%}
    25%  {color:#FF3D87; }
    50%  {color: #CB30FF; }
    100% {color: #FFAABD; top:95%;  left:80%}
}
```

​

Comment: Please give an explnation of what you did understand partially with the help of a code!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a font as background directly but a workaround would be to set the div with the font behind your content (with z-index and absolute positioning) I made an example on codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWrLjR

CSS:

```
.background-font {
  /* Embedd the font you need */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  /* make font not selectable*/
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="background-font">
  Your Background
</div>
<div class="content">
  Your Content<br>
  Goes here<br>
  Another line
</div>
```